# Get Collection after traversing in Umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco5

**Here is my Project Folder Structure into Tree Structure**

```
(*)Root
     []English
            [1]Novel
            [2]Thriller
                    [2.1]Happy
                              [2.1.1]Life Happy
                                           HappyInLife
                                           LoveInLife
                              [2.1.2]Joy
                                           everywhereJoy
                              [2.1.3]Lauging
                                           Always
                                           Sometimes
                                           Never
                    [2.2]Sad
                    [2.3]Excited
                    [2.4]Alone
            [3]Love Story
            [4]Action
     []Hindi
     []Marathi
```

Now here in the above structure I am at node [2.4]Alone
and I want to traverse at node [2.1]Happy. Further I want to access all children , sub children and sub .... of node [2.1] Happy.

**My Project requirement is to display the node [2.1]Happy along with all its children and sub children and so on.... from the node [2.4]Alone**

My Work up till now (I am at node [2.4]Alone)

```
var home=@Model.Parent.Children.First();
```

So home will have the node [2.1]Happy inside it.
but the problem is it will give me only the children of [2.1]Happy and not its Children's children and so on...

I tired using *@Model.AncestorsOrSelf(3);*
but not able to achieve my target .

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think you need to use .Descendants() or .Descendants("docTypeAliasHere"). That will give you EVERYTHING under a node (as in children, grandchildren, grandchildren's children and so on). 

Make sure you know what you're doing because .Descendants() is ok for your example but if you have a node with 5000 items under it, it would make the speed kneel and beg for  mercy.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using uQuery: [(1)](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/uQuery/) [(2)](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/uQuery/Content/Nodes)

Code would look like:

```
@using umbraco

var current = umbraco.NodeFactory.Node.GetCurrent();
var your21Happy = current.Parent.GetChildNodes().First(); // or the way you was getting it already.
var descendants = your21Happy.GetDescendantNodes();
```

uQuery is pretty flexible, you can filter queried nodes by anything, like

```
.GetDescendantNodesByType("uBlogsyPost")
```

or

```
.GetDescendantNodes(x => x.WriterName == "admin")
```

etc.